# How does contiguous block of memory reduce memory access time?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, memory-management

When we use kmalloc() it is said, this function returns contiguous physical blocks of memory (if available) and with vmalloc(), we get non-contiguous block of memory (if available) .

It is further stated, access of contiguous block of memory is faster compared to non-contiguous block of memory [[Source Link]](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand010.html).

To be more specific, lets consider two cases:

Let 1 physical frame=4 KB, page size =4 KB

Case 1:
 In my module code, I am using kmalloc() to allocate 20 KB memory to a char array; call succeeds.

Case 2:
I have done above request using vmalloc() and the call has succeeded.

My questions are:

a) How does it take less time for kmalloc() to fulfil the request compared to vmalloc()?

b) How does contiguous allocation lead to fast access of memory compared to non-contiguous allocation?

In each case, CPU generates virtual address, gives to MMU (if TLB miss), does a page walk, identifies frame number, then converts virtual address to a physical address. How does it matter if address is contiguous or non-contiguous?

Comment: Where is it said that accessing a contiguous block is faster?

Answer (score 0):

For kmalloc the whole physical RAM is already mapped 1:1 with an offset<sup>1</sup>, i.e. physical RAM address N is mapped to virtual address N+PAGE_OFFSET. This makes allocation using kmalloc simpler than with vmalloc, since vmalloc has to find free pages and set up the page tables so that the pages are mapped to a contiguous address block.

There is no difference in access time when accessing kmalloc vs. vmalloc allocated memory, except for the page faults mentioned in the document you linked to.

<sup>1</sup> With the exception of systems with more physical memory than fits in the virtual address space reserved for the kernel.